# Stop receiving signals when running music from terminal

Tags: terminal

I can play music in my music collection by typing:

'vlc somefile.mp3 &'

Which works great except that I always start receiving some signals from the execution of playing that song.

In the following image the signals I dont want to be receiving is the heapload of information that starts running down the screen after the "play_all" command has been run here:
[image]

I don't want to receive those signals, they are irrelevant.

I have already tried adding > /dev/null at the end of the command which I thought would redirect the STDOUT away, but to no avail.

How do I stop receiving signals when running music from the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean with signals?

Comment: I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop receiving the `HUP` (hang up) signal by using `nohup` before your execution command, or you can use bash `disown` command to disable HUP effect for currently running job.

`nohup vlc somefile.mp3 &`

Answer (score 1):

As `nohup` will always generate a file with the output to stdout/stderr you should combine it with output redirection.

The output you see in the terminal is the output to stderr.

When you use `vlc somefile.mp3 > /dev/null &` you only redirect the output of stdout, so you still see the stderr output in the terminal.

To redirect both stdout and stderr and have no file written by `nohup` you can use `nohup vlc somefile.mp3 &> /dev/null &`.

Comment: That works when I type it directly but not when I run it through Perl's system() command.